# How to easily create a lookup table from two vectors in R

Tags: r

I am doing the Hands on Programming in R.

I have two vectors as such:

```
wheel <- c('DD', '7', 'BBB', 'BB', 'B', 'C', '0')
odds = c(0.03, 0.03, 0.06, 0.1, 0.25, 0.01, 0.52)
```

Is there another quick way to write below? It is short list but I figure there must be a quick way if there is a long list.
And do you call prob a vector too?

```
prob = c('DD' = .03, .........'0' = .52)
```

Thank you.  Still learning.

Comment: `prob = setNames(odds, wheel)`. The resulting object is called a 'named vector'

Comment: Yes, `prob` is now called a _named vector_.